# how to call overloaded subscript in a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading, copy-constructor, subscript

If I remove `const` from the copy constructor `MyArray(const MyArray& cArrayInput)`, all is well. Otherwise the following compile error occurs at the line `m_paArray[i] = cArrayInput[i]`:

> error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const MyArray' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

I know I can use `cArrayInput.m_paArray[i]`. But how to use the overloaded subscript function?

```
class MyArray
{
private:
    int m_nLength;
    double* m_paArray;
public:
    MyArray():m_nLength(0),m_paArray(0)
    {
    }
    // copy constructor
    MyArray(const MyArray& cArrayInput)
    {
        m_nLength = cArrayInput.m_nLength;
        m_paArray = new double[m_nLength];
        for(int i=0;i<m_nLength;i++)
            m_paArray[i] = cArrayInput[i];
    }
    double& operator[](const int nIndex)
        {
           assert(nIndex >= 0  && nIndex < m_nLength);
           return m_paArray[nIndex];
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling a non-const operator on a `const` instance of `MyArray`. So you need to provide a `const` version of `operator[]`:

```
const double& operator[](const int nIndex) const
{
  assert(nIndex >= 0  && nIndex < m_nLength);
  return m_paArray[nIndex]; 
}
```

Note that you can provide this version *in addition* to the non-const version.

As an aside, it may be an idea to to something other than call `assert` if the index is out of bounds. You could an throw an exception, for example. That gives the caller code the opportunity to at least recover and do something. The [std::out_of_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception is designed for these cases.